# Spring data elastic search 3 does not support FieldType.String

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In elastic search 2 , I configured string property like below

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, analyzer = "synonym_analyzer")
    private String transformedTitle ;
```

After upgrading to elastic search 5 and spring data elastic search 3.0.0.RC2 , I observe that FieldType.String is no longer available .

Should I use FiledType.Auto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string` field datatype has been replaced by the `text` field for full text analyzed content, and the `keyword` field for not-analyzed exact string values, during the 5.x series.

You should be useing `FieldType.text` or `FieldType.keyword`

Answer (score 1):

As of ES 5, you should be using `FieldType.text`:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.text, analyzer = "synonym_analyzer")
private String transformedTitle ;
```